# su command in ubuntu installed in wubi didn't work

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, wubi

I am new linux user especially on Ubuntu. I've installed Ubuntu Lucid Lynx using in Windows XP using Wubi. When I'm trying install java, it require su command, the instruction on java said I have to put my administrator password on it. Everytime I tried my password, it wont work. Then I realized my account is not an administrator, so I change it to Administrator, but still doesnt work. Any help?

Comment: I dont know your answer is working or not, I should change question or browse Wubi troubleshoots, there are lot of common linux/ubuntu features didnt work in my installation.

Answer (score 4):

do you mean su comand, or sudo command ? - the sudo command needs the password of the normal user, and su needs the root password. By default in ubuntu the root account has no password and you get to it by "becoming root" via sudo.

try `sudo -i` give it your normal password, then do `passwd root` and you should be able to set a password for the root user. Then you can run `su` as a normal user to change user to root.

normal user -> `sudo` -> (user password) -> root for one command
normal user -> `su` -> (root password) -> root until `exit` given.

sudo has configuration to say who can run which commands as root, but by default the user you created at install can do what you need.

does that help / make sense ?

In the long run though, in this particular instance you'd be better off doing `sudo -i` to get root on a temporary basis, and run the installer from there (i.e: as root).

Comment: It's `sudo -i` to start a root shell. (`-l` is for `l`isting the allowed commands)

Comment: doh, sorry typo :)

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, you are "supposed" not to need to use the "su" command. Rather than use "su" to get root priviledges until you use the "exit" command, you are supposed to preceed each command with the "sudo" command.

So

> $ su
>
> # command1
>
> # command2
>
> # command3
>
> # command4
>
> # exit
>
> $

becomes

> $ sudo command1
>
> $ sudo command2
>
> $ sudo command3
>
> $ sudo command4
>
> $

(Note that the prompt changes from "$" to "#" to show that you are root.)

As an alternative, you can use the command "sudo su -" rather than "su" to become root in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo su` and enter your user password when asked for it.